# showing an activity on top of a videoView issues

Tags: android, android-activity, android-videoview

I have an activity that has a `VideoView` widget that plays a mp4 file, when the video is playing I click a button that shows another `Activity`. Before calling the `startActivity()` I called `videoView.stopPlayback()`. 
What happens is that instead of showing the new `Activity`, the current video player `Activity` just finishes. In the log I saw these lines:

```
0-18 09:33:15.488: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(1484): layer=0x54d438 is not in the purgatory list
10-18 09:33:15.488: DEBUG/Zygote(1357): Process 14164 terminated by signal (11)
10-18 09:33:15.508: DEBUG/SurfaceFlinger(1484): layer=0x90ab48 is not in the purgatory list
10-18 09:33:15.528: DEBUG/dalvikvm(14193): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
10-18 09:33:15.538: ERROR/ActivityManager(1484): fail to set top app changed!
```

Can someone point out what could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, turns out the problem is in my code. In the onPause of the launching activity(that with videoView) it called a method that should not be called at the time. The error message from the logcat is confusing. But it appears to me when this message shows,
10-18 09:33:15.538: ERROR/ActivityManager(1484): fail to set top app changed!

that means the app is doing something wrong in the life cycle related methods like onPause, onCreate, onResume.